# How to create a Git Pull Request in GitPython

Tags: python, github, gitpython

I am trying to use python for my jenkins job, this job downloads and refreshes a line in the project then commits and creates a pull request, I am trying read the documentation for GitPython as hard as I can but my inferior brain is not able to make any sense out of it.

```
import git
import os
import os.path as osp


path = "banana-post/infrastructure/"
repo = git.Repo.clone_from('https://github.myproject.git',
                           osp.join('/Users/monkeyman/PycharmProjects/projectfolder/', 'monkey-post'), branch='banana-refresh')
os.chdir(path)

latest_banana = '123456'
input_file_name = "banana.yml"
output_file_name = "banana.yml"
with open(input_file_name, 'r') as f_in, open(output_file_name, 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        if line.startswith("banana_version:"):
            f_out.write("banana_version: {}".format(latest_banana))
            f_out.write("\n")
        else:
            f_out.write(line)
os.remove("deploy.yml")
os.rename("deploy1.yml", "banana.yml")
files = repo.git.diff(None, name_only=True)
for f in files.split('\n'):
    repo.git.add(f)
repo.git.commit('-m', 'This an Auto banana Refresh, contact bannana@monkey.com',
                author='moneky@banana.com')
```

After committing this change I am trying to `push` this change and create a `pull request` from `branch='banana-refresh'` to `branch='banana-integration'`.

Comment: I don't know about GitPython, but you *can* do it from the command line: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull. I imagine GitPython is simply a wrapper around that.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/Mergifyio/git-pull-request) pip Git PR package helps.

Answer (score 9):

[GitPython](https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/) is only a wrapper around Git. I assume you are wanting to create a pull request in a Git hosting service (Github/Gitlab/etc.).

You can't create a pull request using the standard git command line. `git request-pull`, for example, only [Generates a summary of pending changes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull). It doesn't create a pull request in GitHub.

If you want to create a pull request in GitHub, you can use the [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) library.

Or make a simple HTTP request to the Github API with the requests library:

```
import json
import requests

def create_pull_request(project_name, repo_name, title, description, head_branch, base_branch, git_token):
    """Creates the pull request for the head_branch against the base_branch"""
    git_pulls_api = "https://github.com/api/v3/repos/{0}/{1}/pulls".format(
        project_name,
        repo_name)
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "token {0}".format(git_token),
        "Content-Type": "application/json"}

    payload = {
        "title": title,
        "body": description,
        "head": head_branch,
        "base": base_branch,
    }

    r = requests.post(
        git_pulls_api,
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(payload))

    if not r.ok:
        print("Request Failed: {0}".format(r.text))

create_pull_request(
    "<your_project>", # project_name
    "<your_repo>", # repo_name
    "My pull request title", # title
    "My pull request description", # description
    "banana-refresh", # head_branch
    "banana-integration", # base_branch
    "<your_git_token>", # git_token
)
```

This uses the [GitHub OAuth2 Token Auth](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.19/v3/#oauth2-token-sent-in-a-header) and the [GitHub pull request API endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request) to make a pull request of the branch `banana-refresh` against `banana-integration`.

Comment: Request Failed: Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub.
This error comes when I used this script.

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though pull requests have not been wrapped by this library.

You can call the [git command line](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull) directly as per [the documentation](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly).

`repo.git.pull_request(...)`

Comment: I can't find this command in the documentation, can you be little more specific about arguments such as where would feature_branch and target_branch would go?

Comment: The command isn't supported in GitPython. You need to figure out how to run the command using the Git CLI (first link) with your parameters. And then convert that to a GitPython direct call (second link)

Answer (score 1):

I have followed `frederix's` answer also used `https://api.github.com/repos/` instead of  `https://github.com/api/v3/repos/`

Also use **owner_name** instead of **project_name**